# How to disable all other date except from selected date in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepickers named startdate and enddate. I want to disable all other dates except the selected date from startdate.  for example if i selected 15/12/2016 from startdate datepicker then i want to disable all other dates in enddate datepicker except 15th day.

Demofiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d7vzxn8s/

This is my code :

```
 <p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="startdate"></p>
 <p>End Date: <input type="text" id="enddate"></p>

 <script>
   $("#startdate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate());
        $("#enddate").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
      }
    });
  $("#enddate").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modified Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d7vzxn8s/2/

```
var dateToday = new Date();
        var selectedDate;
        $("#startdate").datepicker({
            minDate: dateToday,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                selectedDate = $(this).datepicker( "getDate" );
                var slctdDate = selectedDate.getDate()
               // alert(selectedDate);
                $("#enddate").datepicker({
                minDate: inst.day,
                beforeShowDay: function(date){
                    //Only allow fri, sat

                        return [date.getDate()==slctdDate];

                }
                });

            }
        });

        $("#enddate").datepicker("option");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make only one option to pick in the "`enddate`" selector, it is oblivous that "`enddate`" would equal to "`startdate`".

That's why you can simply copy value from "`startdate`" as you pick it to the "`enddate`" selector and disable "enddate" to be changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two steps:

1. Add the attribute `readonly` to `#enddate`, so that the content cannot be edited or changed by the user;
2. Ensure that when the value of `#startdate` is updated, the value of `#enddate` is then updated too.

Here is the jQuery for Step 2:

```
   $("#startdate").change(function(){
       $("#enddate").val($("#startdate").val());
   });
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#startdate").change(function(){
    $("#enddate").val($("#startdate").val());
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="startdate"></p>
<p>End Date: <input type="text" id="enddate" readonly></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)  But this wont help me. I cant set the enddate ready only. What I really want is , consider if i selected 16/12/2016 then all the previous dates should be disabled (which is the current scenario) and disable all the dates except 16th day after the selected date.
which means i have to select only 16th day of dec 2016, jan 2017, feb 2017, and so on....